# Parsing contents of a large zip file into a html parser into a .csv file

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, csv, multiprocessing

I have some zip files somewhere in the order of 2GB+ containing only html files. Each zip contains about ***170,000*** html files each.

My code reads the file without extracting them,

Passes the resultant html string into a custom HTMLParser object,

And then writes a summary of all the zip files into a CSV (for that particular zipfile).

Despite my code working, it takes longer than a few minutes to completely parse all the files. In order to save the files to a .csv, I've appended the parsed file contents to a list, and then went on to write rows for every entry in the list. I suspect this is what is drawing back performance.

I've also implemented some light multithreading, a new thread is spawned for each zip file encountered. However the magnitude of the files makes me wonder whether I should have implemented a `Process` for each file instead that spawned thread batches to parse the html files(i.e parse 4 files at a time).

My fairly naive attempts at timing the operation revealed the following results when processing 2 zip files at a time:

```
Accounts_Monthly_Data-June2017 has reached file 1500/188495
In: 0.6609588377177715 minutes

Accounts_Monthly_Data-July2017 has reached file 1500/176660
In: 0.7187837697565556 minutes
```

Which implies 12 seconds per 500 files, which is approximately 41 files per second; which is certainly much too slow.

You can find some example zip files at http://download.companieshouse.gov.uk/en_monthlyaccountsdata.html and  an example CSV (for a single html file, the real csv would contain rows for every file) follows:

```
Company Number,Company Name,Cash at bank and in hand (current year),Cash at bank and in hand (previous year),Net current assets (current year),Net current assets (previous year),Total Assets Less Current Liabilities (current year),Total Assets Less Current Liabilities (previous year),Called up Share Capital (current year),Called up Share Capital (previous year),Profit and Loss Account (current year),Profit and Loss Account (previous year),Shareholder Funds (current year),Shareholder Funds (previous year)
07731243,INSPIRATIONAL TRAINING SOLUTIONS LIMITED,2,"3,228","65,257","49,687","65,257","49,687",1,1,"65,258","49,688","65,257","49,687"
```

I fairly new to implementing intermediate, highly-performant code in python so I can't see how I could further optimize what I've written, any suggestions are helpful.

I've provided a test zip of approximately 875 files:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xw3klspg1cipqzx/test.zip?dl=0

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser as HTMLParser
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
import time
import codecs
import zipfile
import os
import csv

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):

    def __init__(self):

        self.fileData = {}  # all the data extracted from this file
        self.extractable = False  # flag to begin handler_data
        self.dataTitle = None  # column title to be put into the dictionary
        self.yearCount = 0
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        yearCount = 0  # years are stored sequentially

        for attrib in attrs:
            if 'name' in attrib[0]:
                if 'UKCompaniesHouseRegisteredNumber' in attrib[1]:
                    self.dataTitle = 'Company Number'
                    # all the parsed files in the directory
                    self.extractable = True
                elif 'EntityCurrentLegalOrRegisteredName' in attrib[1]:
                    self.dataTitle = 'Company Name'
                    self.extractable = True
                elif 'CashBankInHand' in attrib[1]:
                    self.handle_timeSeries_data('Cash at bank and in hand')
                elif 'NetCurrentAssetsLiabilities' in attrib[1]:
                    self.handle_timeSeries_data('Net current assets')
                elif 'ShareholderFunds' in attrib[1]:
                    self.handle_timeSeries_data('Shareholder Funds')
                elif 'ProfitLossAccountReserve' in attrib[1]:
                    self.handle_timeSeries_data('Profit and Loss Account')
                elif 'CalledUpShareCapital' in attrib[1]:
                    self.handle_timeSeries_data('Called up Share Capital')
                elif 'TotalAssetsLessCurrentLiabilities' in attrib[1]:
                    self.handle_timeSeries_data('Total Assets Less Current Liabilities')

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        None

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.extractable == True:
            self.fileData[self.dataTitle] = data
            self.extractable = False

    def handle_timeSeries_data(self, dataTitle):
        if self.yearCount == 0:
            self.yearCount += 1
            self.dataTitle = dataTitle + ' (current year)'
        else:
            self.yearCount = 0
            self.dataTitle = dataTitle + ' (previous year)'

        self.extractable = True


def parseZips(fileName=str()):
    print(fileName)
    directoryName = fileName.split('.')[0]
    zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(fileName, 'r')
    zipFileNames = tuple(n.filename for n in zip_ref.infolist() if 'html' in n.filename or 'htm' in n.filename)
    print('Finished reading ' + fileName+'!\n')
    collectHTMLS(directoryName, zip_ref, zipFileNames)


def collectHTMLS(directoryName, zip_ref, zipFileNames):
    print('Collection html data into a csv for '+ directoryName+'...')
    parser = MyHTMLParser()
    fileCollection = []
    totalFiles = len(zipFileNames)
    count = 0
    startTime = time.time()/60
    for f in zipFileNames:
        parser.feed(str(zip_ref.read(f)))
        fileCollection.append(parser.fileData)
        if(count % 500 ==0):
            print('%s has reached file %i/%i\nIn: {timing} minutes\n'.format(timing = ((time.time()/60)-startTime)) % (directoryName,count,totalFiles))
        parser.fileData = {} #reset the dictionary
        count += 1
    print('Finished parsing files for ' + directoryName)
    with open(directoryName+'.csv', 'w') as f:
        w = csv.DictWriter(f, fileCollection[0].keys())
        w.writeheader()
        for parsedFile in fileCollection:
            w.writerow(parsedFile)
        f.close()
    print('Finished writing to file from ' + directoryName)




def main():
    zipCollection = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f) and f.split('.')[1] == 'zip']
    threadPool = ThreadPool(len(zipCollection))
    threadPool.map_async(parseZips, zipCollection)
    threadPool.close()
    threadPool.join()




main()
```

Comment: perhaps you could add a sample zip-file with a few pages, together with the expected csv for that dataset, so we can verify we end at the same results

Comment: would be nice to know how much of that time is from readint the file, how much for writing so that we can be sure that its an issue with the processing performanse wise

Comment: @juvian I'm putting the data together for you now, I can tell you that it takes approximately 12 seconds to process 500 files

Comment: @MaartenFabré example zip files can be found here: http://download.companieshouse.gov.uk/en_monthlyaccountsdata.html

Comment: I'm creating a small sample csv now

Comment: First suggestion: [Use a profiler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) and don't guess.

Comment: @ferada was not a guess, please see my edits

Comment: @MaartenFabré example csv provided

Comment: @AdrianCoutsoftides my point is that a profiler will show you, somewhat accurately, where it's actually slow, instead of just an average over the run.

Comment: @ferada ahhh yes I see; I'll implement it now

Comment: Can you add a zip with 500-1000 files? dont want to download 1gb to try it

Comment: @juvian https://www.dropbox.com/s/xw3klspg1cipqzx/test.zip?dl=0 here is a test zip

Comment: @AdrianCoutsoftides tried a few things. Basically, all the time is spent on parser.feed. Using lxml is much faster (like x3-6 times faster). Still, if you really only want to process those things, an html parser is overkill and thats the part slowing it down. Processing the html text with a regex would be like x100 times faster, re.compile(r"<ix:([^>]*)>([^<>]*)</ix:.*>") seems to handle the clases you wrote

Comment: @juvian that would make sense; the only issue is that different html files use different xml namespaces; however this can probably be accounted for by meticulously defining as set of regex verfications

Comment: @AdrianCoutsoftides ah I see, picked 2 randomly and saw same ix namespace. Is tag name not the same regardless of namespace? If not, you can always just pick any tag or make a regex for each of the name attributes a tag should have

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the performance, here are some other tips to make this code clearer

## Pep-008

Try to stick to [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for style, especially your variable names are a hodgepodge between `camelCase`, `snake_case` and some hybrid

## long if-elif

If you have a long `if-elif` chain, it will be a pain if later, you want to introduce more info in your CSV. The easiest way to tackle this is to use the appropriate data structure with the parameters. In most cases this is a dict.

```
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    actions = {
       'UKCompaniesHouseRegisteredNumber': {
           'function': '_extract_title',
           'arguments': {
               'title': 'Company Number',
           },
       },
       'EntityCurrentLegalOrRegisteredName': {
           'function': '_extract_title',
           'arguments': {
               'title': 'Company Name',
           },
       },
       'CashBankInHand': {
           'function': '_handle_timeseries_data',
           'arguments': {
               'title': 'Cash at bank and in hand',
           },
       },
       'NetCurrentAssetsLiabilities': {
           'function': '_handle_timeseries_data',
           'arguments': {
               'title': 'Net current assets',
           },
       },
       'ShareholderFunds': {
           'function': '_handle_timeseries_data',
           'arguments': {
               'title': 'Shareholder Funds',
           },
       },
       'ProfitLossAccountReserve': {
           'function': '_handle_timeseries_data',
           'arguments': {
               'title': 'Profit and Loss Account',
           },
       },
       'CalledUpShareCapital': {
           'function': '_handle_timeseries_data',
           'arguments': {
               'title': 'Called up Share Capital',
           },
       },
       'TotalAssetsLessCurrentLiabilities': {
           'function': '_handle_timeseries_data',
           'arguments': {
               'title': 'Total Assets Less Current Liabilities',
           },
       },

    }

    keys = list(chain.from_iterable(
        (action['arguments']['title'],) if action['function'] == '_extract_title'
        else (f"{action['arguments']['title']} (current year)",f"{action['arguments']['title']} (previous year)")
        for action in MyHTMLParser.actions.values()
    ))
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        yearCount = 0  # years are stored sequentially

        for name, action, *_ in attrs:
            if 'name' in name:
                # print(name, action)
                for action_name in self.actions:
                    if action_name not in action:
                        continue
                    action_data = self.actions[action_name]
                    function = action_data['function']
                    kwargs = action_data.get('arguments', {})
                    getattr(self, function)(**kwargs)
                    break
```

Here I used a dict of dicts, but you can also use a list of tuples, etc. This is a balance between simplicity and extensibility.

It would've been easier if the `name` matched exactly with the `action_name`, then you could've used a dict lookup instead of the for-loop.

## Separate functions

your `ParseZips` and `collectHTMLS` do too many things:

There are a few things that need to happen:
- look for the zip-files in the data directory
- look for the html-files inside each zip-file
- parse the html-file
- write the results to a csv

If you delineate each of these parts to it's own function, doing multithreading, multiprocessing or async will be a lot simpler.

This makes testing each of the separate parts easier too

### parse a simple html-file

```
def parse_html(html: str):
    parser = MyHTMLParser()
    parser.feed(html)
    return parser.file_data
```

as simple as can be.

> ```
> {'Company Number': '00010994',
>  'Company Name': 'BARTON-UPON-IRWELL LIBERAL CLUB BUILDING COMPANY LIMITED',
>  'Called up Share Capital (current year)': '2,509',
>  'Called up Share Capital (previous year)': '2,509',
>  'Cash at bank and in hand (current year)': '-',
>  'Cash at bank and in hand (previous year)': '-',
>  'Net current assets (current year)': '400',
>  'Net current assets (previous year)': '400',
>  'Total Assets Less Current Liabilities (current year)': '3,865',
>  'Total Assets Less Current Liabilities (previous year)': '3,865',
>  'Profit and Loss Account (current year)': '393',
>  'Profit and Loss Account (previous year)': '393',
>  'Shareholder Funds (current year)': '2,116',
>  'Shareholder Funds (previous year)': '2,116'}
> ```

This uses a new parser for each html-string. If you want to reuse the parser, something as this can work:

```
def parse_html2(html: str, parser=None):
    if parser is None:
        parser = MyHTMLParser()
    else:
        parser.file_data = {}
    parser.feed(html)
    return parser.file_data
```

### parse a zip-file:

```
def parse_zip(zip_filehandle):
    for file_info in zip_filehandle.infolist():
        content = str(zip_filehandle.read(file_info))
        data = parse_html(content)
        yield data
```

this is a simple generator that takes an opened ZipFile as argument. If you ever want to multiprocess each individual html-file, only smaller changes are needed in this function.

### writing the results

```
def write_zip(zipfile: Path, out_file: Path = None):
    if out_file is None:
        out_file = zipfile.with_suffix('.csv')

    with ZipFile(zip_file) as zip_filehandle, out_file.open('w') as out_filehandle:
        # num_files = len(zip_filehandle.infolist())
        writer = DictWriter(out_filehandle, MyHTMLParser.keys)
        writer.writeheader()
        for i, data in enumerate(parse_zip(zip_filehandle)):
            # print(f'{i} / {num_files}')
            writer.writerow(data)
```

This uses `pathlib.Path` for the files, which makes handling the extension and opening the file a bit easier.

### putting it together

```
def main_naive(data_dir):
    for zipfile in data_dir.glob('*.zip'):
        write_zip(zipfile)
```

Here, I would use `pathlib.Path.glob` instead of `os.listdir`

### multithreaded

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
def main_threaded(data_dir, max_threads=None):
    zip_files = list(data_dir.glob('*.zip'))
    num_threads = len(zip_files) if max_threads is None else min(len(zip_files), max_threads)
    with ThreadPool(num_threads) as threadPool:
        threadPool.map_async(write_zip, zip_files)
        threadPool.close()
        threadPool.join()
```

Also here, using a context-manager (`with`) to prevent problems when something throws an exception

## Optimizing

Now you have separated the reading, parsing and writing the results, profiling will be easier, and which step to tackle first will depend on the results of the profiling. If the bottleneck is the IO, the physical reading of the file, throwing more threads at it will not speed up the process, but using loading the zip files into memory might

Comment: This is a great start! While I initially used a new parser for each html file; I thought this came at a performance overhead, wouldn't reusing a single parser be more effective in terms of memory management and possibly speed?

Answer (score 0):

The upload's very useful, thanks.  So it looks like the files aren't
that messy, like what already was said, an approach based on regular
expressions might be sufficient, if there's no line breaks or similar
stuff it certainly could be pretty fast.  Parser-wise the only other
option, that isn't really going to be quicker ... probably, would be to
see if any of the other parsers, possibly just [a SAX-based one](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.sax.html), can
process the files quicker.  Again, if you're already going for regex
this won't matter.

Edit: Nevermind.  I was going to suggest to skip parsing as soon as there's nothing more interesting in the file, but clearly the data is contained all over.

Lastly, this is Python, you could look whether PyPy improves speed, but with CPython I wouldn't expect any high performance (by itself) to be honest.

---

Edit: I tried the SAX approach and now that I look at it more closely I'm noticing some bugs, specifically there are multiple tags with similar names and the `if` statements are overwriting some data, e.g. there's both "CalledUpShareCapital" and "CalledUpShareCapitalNotPaidNotExpressedAsCurrentAsset", only the first one of which should probably be taken, but in the original version the second one makes it to the CSV.  For "NORMANTON BRICK COMPANY LIMITED" there's also a free text comment that made it into the CSV, again because the tag name was matched too loosely.

Also some text fields are cut off in the original script, e.g. company names.

There's also the one line with `yearCount = 0` that doesn't do anything (since it needs a `self.` as a prefix.

So with all that, below the script as it is right now:

```
import xml.sax
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
import time
import codecs
import zipfile
import os
import csv


class MyHTMLParser(xml.sax.ContentHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        xml.sax.ContentHandler.__init__(self)
        self._reset()

    def _reset(self):
        self.fileData = {} # all the data extracted from this file
        self.extractable = False # flag to begin handler_data
        self.dataTitle = None # column title to be put into the dictionary
        self.yearCount = 0
        self.level = 0
        self.endLevel = -1

    def startElement(self, tag, attrs):
        self.level += 1

        if tag not in ('ix:nonNumeric', 'ix:nonFraction'):
            return

        for attrib in attrs.keys():
            if attrib.endswith('name'):
                name = attrs[attrib]
                if 'UKCompaniesHouseRegisteredNumber' in name:
                    self.dataTitle = 'Company Number'
                    self.extractable = self.dataTitle not in self.fileData
                elif 'EntityCurrentLegalOrRegisteredName' in name:
                    self.dataTitle = 'Company Name'
                    self.extractable = self.dataTitle not in self.fileData
                elif 'CashBankInHand' in name:
                    self.handle_timeSeries_data('Cash at bank and in hand')
                elif 'NetCurrentAssetsLiabilities' in name:
                    self.handle_timeSeries_data('Net current assets')
                elif 'ShareholderFunds' in name:
                    self.handle_timeSeries_data('Shareholder Funds')
                elif 'ProfitLossAccountReserve' in name:
                    self.handle_timeSeries_data('Profit and Loss Account')
                elif 'CalledUpShareCapital' in name and 'NotPaid' not in name:
                    self.handle_timeSeries_data('Called up Share Capital')
                elif 'TotalAssetsLessCurrentLiabilities' in name:
                    self.handle_timeSeries_data('Total Assets Less Current Liabilities')
                else:
                    break
                self.endLevel = self.level

    def endElement(self, name):
        if self.endLevel != -1 and self.endLevel == self.level:
            # print("end level %s reached, closing for %s and %s" % (self.endLevel, name, self.dataTitle))
            self.endLevel = -1
            self.extractable = False
        self.level -= 1

    def characters(self, data):
        if self.extractable:
            if self.dataTitle not in self.fileData:
                self.fileData[self.dataTitle] = ''
            self.fileData[self.dataTitle] += data

    def handle_timeSeries_data(self, dataTitle):
        if self.yearCount == 0:
            self.yearCount += 1
            self.dataTitle = dataTitle + ' (current year)'
        else:
            self.yearCount = 0
            self.dataTitle = dataTitle + ' (previous year)'

        self.extractable = self.dataTitle not in self.fileData


def parseZips(fileName):
    print(fileName)
    directoryName = fileName.split('.')[0]
    zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(fileName, 'r')
    zipFileNames = tuple(n.filename for n in zip_ref.infolist() if 'html' in n.filename or 'htm' in n.filename)
    print('Finished reading ' + fileName+'!\n')
    collectHTMLS(directoryName, zip_ref, zipFileNames)


def collectHTMLS(directoryName, zip_ref, zipFileNames):
    print('Collection html data into a csv for '+ directoryName+'...')
    parser = MyHTMLParser()
    fileCollection = []
    totalFiles = len(zipFileNames)
    count = 0
    startTime = time.time()/60
    for f in zipFileNames:
        with zip_ref.open(f) as stream:
            xml.sax.parse(stream, parser)
        fileCollection.append(parser.fileData)
        if count % 500 == 0:
            print('%s has reached file %i/%i\nIn: {timing} minutes\n'.format(timing = ((time.time()/60)-startTime)) % (directoryName,count,totalFiles))
        parser._reset()
        count += 1
    print('Finished parsing files for ' + directoryName)
    with open(directoryName+'.csv', 'w') as f:
        w = csv.DictWriter(f, fileCollection[0].keys())
        w.writeheader()
        for parsedFile in fileCollection:
            w.writerow(parsedFile)
    print('Finished writing to file from ' + directoryName)


def main():
    zipCollection = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f) and f.split('.')[1] == 'zip']
    threadPool = ThreadPool(len(zipCollection))
    threadPool.map_async(parseZips, zipCollection)
    threadPool.close()
    threadPool.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Edit: Oh yeah and also if you write CSV, make sure that you fix the order of keys, otherwise it can be completely random what you get from a `dict`, which makes comparing output files `diff`icult.